# Why using Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE could not send using only gmail applications

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail

I have 2 cases when trying to send simple text and second text and attach image .For the first case I could send using only gmail clients and with defined email. while for the second case it displays other applications installed on the device(Bluetooth, WhatsApp and if I'm using gmail it doesn't show in the field of To the defined email address.

val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:" + context.resources.getString(R.string.email)))
startActivity(emailIntent)

val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE, Uri.parse("mailto:" + view.resources.getString(R.string.email)))
startActivity(emailIntent)

Comment: `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` [does not use the `Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE).

Comment: But if I use it without Uri   how can I send using gmail application and to defined to email address?

Comment: You are welcome to [use `EXTRA_EMAIL` to indicate potential addresses](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_EMAIL), if the user chooses an email app. Neither `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` nor `ACTION_SENDTO` are limited to email apps, though `ACTION_SENDTO` and a `mailto:` `Uri` *usually* only route to email apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok I see,EXTRA_EMAIL works, but I didn't get the part for GMAIL apps , I mean to display options only of GMAIL apps

Comment: There is no "display options only of GMAIL apps" with `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`, if you mean "only allow the user to share via an email app". Allow the user to [share where the user wants](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/28/share-where-the-user-wants.html). If the user wants to share with Evernote or Google Drive or Dropbox or Facebook or Twitter, that is the user's decision to make.